# Put WHERE clause on Pandas Merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge, where-clause

I have two pandas data frames that I am trying to merge together on three different keys ... kind of. Each data frame has a gender column, and a country_destination column which I want to do the outer join on. One data frame has an age_bucket column which is a string representing the age range e.g. 45-49, 50-54, 55-59 which I have turned into a list in another column with the pandas apply method. My question is when you do a join between two data frame on multiple keys, can you also do a where statement somewhere in order to be able to join on columns that don't share the same exact data types ? For example could I say "Join these tables on gender, and country_destination columns where the age of a user is IN the list value of age_gender's age_list column"

```
age_gender = pd.read_csv('data/age_gender_bkts.csv')
users = pd.read_csv('data/train_users_2.csv')

def getAgeList(row):
    clean_age = row['age_bucket'].replace('+', '')
    min_max = clean_age.split('-')

    if len(min_max) > 1:
        min_max = list(range(int(min_max[0]), int(min_max[1]) + 1))
    return min_max

age_gender['age_list'] = age_gender.apply(lambda x: getAgeList(x), axis=1)

combined_df = pd.merge(users, age_gender, on=['country_destination', 'gender'])
```

user.columns

```
Index(['id', 'date_account_created', 'timestamp_first_active',
       'date_first_booking', 'gender', 'age', 'signup_method', 'signup_flow',
       'language', 'affiliate_channel', 'affiliate_provider',
       'first_affiliate_tracked', 'signup_app', 'first_device_type',
       'first_browser', 'country_destination', 'lat_destination',
       'lng_destination', 'distance_km', 'destination_km2',
       'destination_language ', 'language_levenshtein_distance'],
      dtype='object')
```

age_gender.columns

```
Index(['age_bucket', 'country_destination', 'gender',
       'population_in_thousands', 'year', 'age_list'],
      dtype='object')
```

DataFrame Samples
[image][image]

Comment: Why don't you filter the dataframe before the merge?

Comment: Can you add some data samples, 2-4 rows for each dataframe with desired output? I think [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: Also there is a lot of columns, it seems 2 - 3 columns in each dataframe is only necessary in samples.

Comment: Yeah, I will upload photos of the head of each data frame with only some of its most important columns.

Comment: It stills needs some cleaning, but I was just curious if this was possible.

Comment: Please [Don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), is possible copy samples as text?

Comment: Let me check it out jezrael, just a moment.

Comment: Sorry, I try add solution without your sample, I hope it works, if some problem let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need expand rows by values in `age_list` column and then `merge`:

```
#get lengths of each list
l = age_gender['age_list'].str.len()
#get all columns without age_list
cols = age_gender.columns.difference(['age_list'])
#repeat values by lengths to new DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({col: np.repeat(age_gender[col].values, l) for col in cols})
#flattening lists, necessary convert to int, because merge not match
df['age'] = np.concatenate(age_gender['age_list'].values).astype(int)

#inner merge is default, so how='inner' is omit
df1 = pd.merge(df, users, on=['age', 'country_destination'])
```

Comment: Champion ! I feel like there should be a built in way to do this in pandas.merge, but this still gets me what I need : ). Thank you, I will have to look for ways to copy over Pandas dataframes in text so I don't have to post pictures of them.

Comment: Thank you. I try a bit describe solution, give me a second.

Comment: Ah the power of python. Thanks for the description jezrael ! it's really appreciated.

Comment: Super, glad can help. Nice day!